import SQL data into a database using Node.js and Sequelize
optimizing the execution time for inserting a large volume of data into the database using Sequelize
Initially, I was running around 20,000 queries individually through Sequelize, but it was taking too much time. To improve performance, I started concatenating the queries and executing them in batches of 500 using Sequelize's raw query function. While this approach helped to some extent, I'm still exploring alternative methods that could further enhance efficiency.
Specifically, I'm considering whether writing the queries to a file and then importing that file into the database through Sequelize could be a more efficient approach. However, I'm unsure about the feasibility and potential benefits of this method compared to the batch execution method I'm currently using.
Overall, my goal is to find the most efficient way to insert a large volume of data into the database using Sequelize, and I'm seeking insights or suggestions from the community on how to achieve this.

I'm considering whether writing the queries to a file and then importing that file into the database through Sequelize could be a more efficient approach. I doubt.. I'm still exploring alternative methods that could further enhance efficiency. Start transaction. Execute queries. Commit transaction. the most efficient way to insert a large volume of data into the database You'd insert data only, i.e. multiple rows in one query and not multiple queries.

whats stopping you from writing a humongous sql insert statement?

What do these queries look like? Could you show a couple of examples?

@Akina yes, you are right. Before this, I was using the same approach, but as the total queries increased, the time to run them became around 2 hours

but as the total queries increased You must collapse multiple INSERTs to one INSERT with many data rows.
